# Maximum Update Depth Exceeded Error when Navigating after login in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

On login click I am hitting the login api to login and setting the response in states in redux toolkit.

This is the login button listener:

```js
export const SigninApi = (toast, nav) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
    const password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;

    if (!username) {
      dispatch(setUsernameError("Username is required"));
      return;
    } else {
      dispatch(setUsernameError(""));
    }

    if (!password) {
      dispatch(setPasswordError("Password is required"));
      return;
    } else {
      dispatch(setPasswordError(""));
    }
    const formdata = {
      username: username,
      password: password,
      domain: window.location.origin,
    };

    dispatch(setLoading(true));

    let response = await axios.post(`${baseurl}/login`, formdata);

    console.log;

    if (Object.keys(response.data.data.user).length !== 0) {
      const token = JSON.stringify(response?.data?.data?.user?.token);
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      dispatch(setToken(token));

      const jsonData = JSON.stringify(response.data?.data?.user);
      localStorage.setItem("user", jsonData);
      dispatch(setUser(response?.data?.data?.user));

      toast({
        title: "Success",
        description: "Signin Successfully.",
        status: "success",
        isClosable: true,
        position: "top-right",
      });

      nav.push("/admin");
    } else {
      dispatch(setUser(null));
      dispatch(setToken(null));

      console.log("error", response?.data?.message);

      toast({
        title: "Singin Error",
        description: response?.data?.message,
        status: "error",
        duration: 3000,
        isClosable: true,
        position: "top-right",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(setUser(null));
    dispatch(setToken(null));
    console.log("error", error);
    toast({
      title: "SingIn Error",
      description: error?.response?.data?.message,
      status: "error",
      duration: 3000,
      isClosable: true,
    });
  }
};
```

After setting states when I navigate to `'/admin'` or `'/'` or `'/admin/dashboard'` or any route I get this error:

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

If I don't route and just do `window.location.reload()`, there is no error

I am using `useHistory()` hook of `react-router-dom` (I know I am using old version of `react-router-dom` which supports `useHistory`)
passing nav as an argument which is

```js
const nav = useHistory();
```

and same error when I navigate after logout.
I dont know what is the problem because I am navigating everywhere in other components and there is no issue at all

This is Index.js where I am handling parent routes

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth.jsx";
import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.jsx";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";
import { ColorModeScript } from "@chakra-ui/system";
import theme from "theme/theme";
import PageNotFound from "views/404/PageNotFound";
import "./index.css";

const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("token")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))
  : null;

// HOC for authenticated routes
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) =>
      !isAuthenticated ? (
        <Redirect to="/auth/signin" />
      ) : (
        <Component {...props} />
      )
    }
  />
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />
        <Route path="/404" component={PageNotFound} />
        <ProtectedRoute path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} />
        <Redirect
          exact
          from="/"
          to={!isAuthenticated ? "/auth/signin" : "/admin/dashboard"}
        />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: We can't address issues in the code we can't see. Please do [edit] the post to include a ***complete*** [mcve] of all the relevant code you are working with. Seems like you may be creating a render loop somewhere where you are handling redirecting or protecting routes based on the auth status.

Comment: @DrewReese I ediited the post and include index.js file code, please check the routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isAuthenticated` value isn't checked as a condition of *entering* the route. It is computed once when the code loads and never changes.

Update `ProtectedRoute` to check localStorage when accessing the route. Move the `isAuthenticated` computation *into* the component.

Example:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("token")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))
    : null;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        !isAuthenticated ? (
          <Redirect to="/auth/signin" />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Also, a more conventional way to implement `ProtectedRoute` is as follows:

```
const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("token")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))
    : null;

  return !isAuthenticated
    ? (
      <Redirect to="/auth/signin" />
    ) : (
      <Route {...props} />
    );
};
```